# One microservice doing many transformations or many microservices doing one transformation?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, .net-core, microservices, docker-swarm

I have a service that transforms XML documents.
It receives a messages from N queues and depending on from which queue it gets the message from it runs one of the transformations.

Now I'm refactoring it to be a microservice running in docker container.
I think I can do it in two ways but I don't know which of them would be a better practice when using containers.

I'm doing this in .NET Core 2.2. I don't know yet whether we will use docker-swarm or kubernetes on production.

1. I could just leave most of the code like it is now and run it as one container.  AppSettings.config would contain settings for every queue-transformation pair.

   **The pros I see:**
   Less code changes needed and simpler docker-compose - one service instead of N.     Only one config file.

   **The cons:**
   If there is a higher demand for one of transformations or if it has
   higher priority I can't just scale it's container. New replicas
   would be pulling messages from all queues instead of just one that I want to scale for.
2. I could refactor the code and build N different container images.
   Each of them would listen to one queue and run one transformation. I can refactor it so that
   the only difference in code is in Startup when registering services. Based on configuration I could
   register one of IXmlTransformers.

   **Pros:**
   I can scale for one queue-transformation.
   If there is a problem with one of the transformations and container restarts all other transformations will work normally.
   I think it's cleaner - one image is doing one transformation - Single responsibility rule.

   **Cons:**
   In some environments there will be around 10 different transformations therefore
   There will be a lot of configuration files - probably added to each running container using a volume?
   Docker compose will be very long.

   What would be a better way to do it? Or maybe there are other better options?

**Edit:**

I think I wasn't clear with my question so I try to explain it better.
In both options I would have one container image. The difference would be at runtime. Only configuration would be different.
Let's say I'm transforming XML to CSV or XML to XML using XSLT.
CSV format and XSLT are part of configuration. I can have many CSV formats (many configurations) and many different XSLTs (again many configurations)
So I have two ITransformer implementations (CSV, XSLT) and they read configuration to run their transformations.
And my question is whether it is better to have one running container instance for one config or put all those configs into one container which monitors N queues or monitors one queue and reads some kind of metadata to decide which transformation to run.

Comment: Do first, but expose queue configuration, so that you're able to bring up a container that listens only to this queue (or handles messages from this queue before all others')

Comment: Big 'It depends' here. As you pointed out, scalability-wise and Single Responsibility Principle would suggest option 2 but try to factor in how many people will be maintaining those services, how much do they have in common and how often are they likely to change as you'd have to go through all of them, and obviously the cost of running N services vs 1. If it's a small project or unlikely to change, I'd go for option1, as long as it doesn't get horrendously complicated.

Comment: I think I used wrong vocabulary. I said in option 2 I would build N different container images. But I meant that at runtime I would run N of them but they would share image. Only configuration would be different.
And in option 1 there would be one image and one running container.

Answer (score 1):

> The cons: If there is a higher demand for one of transformations or if
>   it has higher priority I can't just scale it's container. New replicas
>   would be pulling messages from all queues instead of just one that I
>   want to scale for.

Why is it an issue that all queues are being pulled? Is it because you usually have a large backlog in the queues or are you afraid of providing overcapacity? When all queues are up to date with processing only the one queue that you wanted to scale should be picked up anyway.

In case you can't do that I would still go with generic service that can pull from all queues, but try to incorporate a weighting or other rule set based on queue length, timestamps of queue entries or whatever is appropriate in your case to regulate what queue is pulled with what priority. If the right result parameter of this logic is exposed it can also be used to auto-scale your cluster if are are too behind.

The alternative of manual scaling based on queues sounds like it could turn into an admin nightmare.

Comment: I thought about situation where rate of messages coming to one of queues is larger than for other queues. Let's say the ratio is 1:3 between two different queues. If I have one service for listening to both of them or one listening to each of them the number of messages in queue with higher message ratio might grow even though I handle them. But now when I think of it it I'm not sure it makes sense. If there is a lot more messages in one of queues they will be handled more often right?

Answer (score 1):

When you have the context of which job should run in the name of the queue or event, it shouldn't be a problem to use the same code in multiple containers also with the same config. I don't know your setup, but I would avoid binding one container to one queue. Containers shouldn't be deployed with state, when you can avoid it.

Depending on amount of files and money you have, you could also use an approach with amazon lambda and S3. No need for any message queueing or own infrastructure when you go with S3 and different bucket names, which are triggering a lambda function on upload. It's not a better approach it's just a different one and it hardly depends on your needs. It can be cheaper, or much more expensive than your approach, which also depends on your use case.

Comment: The code is same, but configs are different. Let's say I need to run XSLT or transformation to CSV. Xslt and CSV definition is part of config then.

Comment: From the information you gave so far, I would go with option 1. of your description from above and try to solve the priorisation of the queues/messages separately. E.g. http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-support-priority-queues.html https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html or find the concept you can use with your chosen message queue.